# How to upload csv file in angular 13 Error:"my-app"

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am studying angular.

I created a csv file to upload with the following source code,
The screen is completely blank with nothing displayed.

[nothing displayed is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a75uT.png)

Is it not displayed depending on the version?

Reference URL

[Angular Upload Readcsv | stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-upload-readcsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

[Read CSV and convert JSON Data in Angular](https://www.eduforbetterment.com/read-csv-and-convert-json-data-in-angular/)

**Console error**

```
ERROR Error: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements
    at DefaultDomRenderer2.selectRootElement (platform-browser.mjs:580:19)
    at locateHostElement (core.mjs:9830:1)
    at ComponentFactory.create (core.mjs:21603:1)
    at ApplicationRef.bootstrap (core.mjs:26538:1)
    at core.mjs:26219:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap (core.mjs:26219:1)
    at core.mjs:26189:1
    at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:372:1)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:25608:1)
```

**app.component.ts**

```
/*
https://www.eduforbetterment.com/
*/
import { Component, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class CsvData {
    public id: any;
    public min: any;
    public max: any;
    public score: any;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  public records: any[] = [];
  @ViewChild('csvReader') csvReader: any;
  jsondatadisplay:any;

  uploadListener($event: any): void {

    let text = [];
    let files = $event.srcElement.files;

    if (this.isValidCSVFile(files[0])) {

      let input = $event.target;
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);

      reader.onload = () => {
        let csvData = reader.result;
        let csvRecordsArray = (<string>csvData).split(/\r\n|\n/);

        let headersRow = this.getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArray);

        this.records = this.getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray, headersRow.length);
      };

      reader.onerror = function () {
        console.log('error is occured while reading file!');
      };

    } else {
      alert("Please import valid .csv file.");
      this.fileReset();
    }
  }

  getDataRecordsArrayFromCSVFile(csvRecordsArray: any, headerLength: any) {
    let csvArr = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < csvRecordsArray.length; i++) {
      let curruntRecord = (<string>csvRecordsArray[i]).split(',');
      if (curruntRecord.length == headerLength) {
        let csvRecord: CsvData = new CsvData();
        csvRecord.id = curruntRecord[0].trim();
        csvRecord.min = curruntRecord[1].trim();
        csvRecord.max = curruntRecord[2].trim();
        csvRecord.score = curruntRecord[3].trim();
        csvArr.push(csvRecord);
      }
    }
    return csvArr;
  }

//check etension
  isValidCSVFile(file: any) {
    return file.name.endsWith(".csv");
  }

  getHeaderArray(csvRecordsArr: any) {
    let headers = (<string>csvRecordsArr[0]).split(',');
    let headerArray = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
      headerArray.push(headers[j]);
    }
    return headerArray;
  }

  fileReset() {
    this.csvReader.nativeElement.value = "";
    this.records = [];
    this.jsondatadisplay = '';
  }

  getJsonData(){
    this.jsondatadisplay = JSON.stringify(this.records);
  }


}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Upload csv to read
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

      <input type="file" #csvReader name="Upload CSV" id="txtFileUpload" (change)="uploadListener($event)"
        accept=".csv" />

    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="javascript:;" *ngIf="records.length > 0" (click)="getJsonData()" class="btn btn-primary">Convert Json </a>

  <a href="javascript:;" *ngIf="records.length > 0" (click)="fileReset()" class="btn btn-primary">Reset </a>

  {{jsondatadisplay}}
  <table class="table" *ngIf="records.length > 0">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Min</th>
        <th scope="col">Max</th>
        <th scope="col">Score</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let record of records;let i = index;">
        <th scope="row">{{record.id}}</th>
        <td>{{record.min}}</td>
        <td>{{record.max}}</td>
        <td>{{record.score}}</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**app.component.css**

```
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}
.table,.container{
  margin-top:20px; 
}
.btn{
  margin-right:20px; 
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click) = "downloadCSV()" > Download CSV</button >

    status: any[];
formula: string = "Formula 1";
downloadCSV() {
    this.status = ["approved", "rejected", "pending"];
    var data = [
        {
            name: "Test 1",
            age: 13,
            average: 8.2,
            status: this.status[0],
            description: "Kuala Lmpuer, Malaysia"
        },
        {
            name: 'Test 2',
            age: 11,
            average: 8.2,
            status: this.status[1],
            description: "Jakarta, Indonesia"
        },
        {
            name: 'Test 3',
            age: 10,
            average: 8.2,
            status: this.status[2],
            description: "Bangkok, Thailand"
        },
    ];

    var options = {
        title: 'User Details',
        fieldSeparator: ',',
        quoteStrings: '"',
        decimalseparator: '.',
        showLabels: true,
        showTitle: true,
        useBom: true,
        headers: ['Name', 'Age', 'Average', 'Status', 'Address']
    }; `enter code here`

    new Angular2Csv(data, this.formula, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check again the console in your browser to check the error.

[This is an image in my local when applying your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTUqB.png)

Or run again `npm i` to make sure to apply the newest lib.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I don't get any errors. And I also tried npm i but I still get the white screen.

Comment: Sorry I found an Error: The selector "my-app" did not match any element

Comment: Yeah, enjoy it. Good luck,